# How to get a list of available supported languages and set one?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

My app supports some languages and I have added those and have some files like: `AppResources.resx`, `AppResources.fr.resx` and so one.

I change the language like this:

```
RootFrame.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(AppResources.ResourceLanguage);

FlowDirection flow = (FlowDirection)Enum.Parse(typeof(FlowDirection), AppResources.ResourceFlowDirection);
RootFrame.FlowDirection = flow;
```

By default it depends on phones language, but I want to change it inside the app, by user choice.

In the above code, I can hardcode and replace `AppResources.ResourceLanguage` with `en-US`.. But is there a better way.

How to get a list of available supported languages and set it?

(it is WP8)

Answer (score 0):

In the code, you can read the manifest xml file for list of supported languages for user selection in the app. And as a binding, you can set the current UI thread culture as user selected language rather than phone language in app.xaml.cs